# Select from multiple tables using a join where a column in another table applies?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im creating a table booking system and have these tables,

- booking
- sitting
- table_info
- table_sitting

The booking table contains information about the table booking specific to the customer, like their name, phone number and amount of people.

The sitting table links a seperate system into this system and contains the sitting, which is either lunch or evening and also the date.

The table_info table contains information about the tables in the restaurant, such as the max seating and location.

The table_sitting table links these three tables together with the primary key's from booking, sitting, and table_sitting, (booking_id, sitting_id, table_number).

I need to be able to show a list of the tables that are both booked and non-booked, I achieved this with a right join between table_sitting and table_info. 
However I want to be able to only show the booked tables from a date to a week ahead of said date.

The sitting table holds the date information.